need to identify this 6-pin SMD IC marked -L361
Can someone help me to identify this 6-pin SMD IC,
It's from power supply 230vAC to 54V DC 3A.
I tried to take pictures from several different angles, including a microscope, but unfortunately this is the clearest result I was able to take a picture of.
This component is burned, so it may be difficult to identify what is written.
When I tried to take it out, the component crumbled and fell apart...
Unfortunately, I have to fix it as soon as possible because it belongs to my network switch. And I am disabled because of it.
And is there another component that could also fit?
Thanks





Can you give exact product as there could be many 230V AC to 54V DC w/3A

Please could you try and clean the IC and take photos from other angles  You're missing part of the marking code - something like C?-L361, but can't read the second digit. Also a photograph of the surrounding circuitry can help give clues.
